# nuxt.js. mode: spa. problem in not root path on production

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, nuxt.js

I am a Japanese not good at English sorry.

I have a nuxt project like this.

The mode is spa.

**Directory construction**

```
pages - index.vue
        index
          |_ child.vue
          |_ index.vue
```

**pages/index.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ title }}
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    title () {
      let title = ''
      if (this.$route.path === '/') {
        title = 'Parent'
      } else if (this.$route.path === '/child') {
        title = 'Child'
      }
      return title
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When I build(or generate), you can get static file of **child/index.html**.

I upload inside the dist to server.

But if I access to http://deployedrootpath/child, the computed property doesn't work.

I think this happens because these static files are created before created hook.

It can only know returned value from asyncData hook.

So I did like this.

**middleware/redirect.js**

```
export default function ({ route, redirect }) {
  if (route.path === '/child/') {
    // I need to set some params because of navigation duplication error of vue-router.
    redirect('/child', { params: { 'redirect': true } })
  }
}
```

**pages/index/child.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    child
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 middleware: 'redirect'
}
</script>
```

Actually it worked but I know this is a terrible way.

And even if there is no way except for this, I want to at least hide params from redirected url.

Please help me.

Comment: try `mounted` hook  in your `page/index` instead of computed

Comment: Thank you. Actually the problem was because of difference between url's path and $route.path and I wanted to make them equal. So I used ```trailingSlash: true```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved.

**nuxt.config.js**

```
trailingSlash: true
```

This make the static files path and $route.path same.

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/#trailingslash